# Is there any way to update installschema.php to dbschema.xml?

Tags: db-schema

How to create dbschema.xml from installschema.php

Answer (score 1):

Steps Taken To Generate the db_schema.xml file Automatically for any extension Example : VendorName_ModuleName
-> Delete the Module entry from setup_module table
-> Delete all the Related tables Used in your Extension
-> After that Run the command on magento root

```
 - bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1
 - bin/magento setup:upgrade --convert-old-scripts=1
```

The Above command will Generate the db_schema.xml file Under VendorName/ModuleName/etc/Directory

Reference Links :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html

Answer (score 0):

To Generate the db_schema.xml file Automatically for any extension Example : VendorName_ModuleName

-> Delete the Module entry from setup_module table

-> Delete all the Related tables Used in your Extension

-> After that Run the command on magento root

```
 - bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1
 - bin/magento setup:upgrade --convert-old-scripts=1
```

The Above command will Generate the db_schema.xml file Under VendorName/ModuleName/etc/ Directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me

Comment: Great to here from your side.